# Function Macro gerring : undefined reference to `Printf' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define AVERAGE 25
#define MIN (AVERAGE - 5)
#define MAX (AVERAGE + 5)


#define CHECK(value) if(value < AVERAGE){\
                printf("small value");\
                    } \
                else if(value >AVERAGE){\
                        printf("big value");\
                    }else{Printf("it is average");  }

int main()
{

int num=0;
int i;
CHECK(num);

return 0;
}
```

and the error I got after compilation is:

```
/home/solomon/c_revision/macros.c:22: undefined reference to `Printf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

where c:22 is the place I call check. I do not know why it is giving me the error above. can someone help

Comment: Typo: `Printf("it is average");` --> `printf("it is average");`.

Comment: I'm quite sure you had warning complaining that Printf is implicitly declared?

Answer (score 1):

Typographical error, change in macro

```
Printf("it is average") to printf("it is average")
```